# Using "wish" to express regret in the present and in the past

Tags: meaning, grammar, present-perfect, wish-preterite, irrealis-were

> I wish I have been there for the baby kicking for the first time?

Could I change the sentence to

> I wish I was there for the baby kicking for the first time?

What are the differences between the two sentences?

Comment: As you mention tense, bear in mind that there are several "perfects" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_(grammar)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both sentences given are slightly incorrect, I’m afraid.  I think the form you want is probably

> I wish I had been there for…

(In speech or informal writing, this would often be contracted: “I wish I’d been there for…”) Also good, as Robusto said, is

> I wish I could have been there for…

although this only works if your absence was unintentional — if you knew when to expect it and just chose not to go, this version doesn’t apply.

The versions

> I wish I were there for…

> I wish I was there for…

are appropriate for an event happening *right now*, not for something that happened in the past.  You might have a phone conversation: “The baby is kicking right now!” “Oh!  I wish I were there for it!”

The form

> *I wish I have been there for…

isn’t correct for anything (although it’s a fairly common error among non-native speakers, and people wouldn’t have difficulty understanding it).

Comment: Hey, poor *were* asks why he wasn't given preference over his stepbrother...

Comment: I agonised over this; but a maxim I try to follow (with limited success) is “say one thing at a time”.  A discussion of the subtleties of *were* vs. *was* here would get in the way of the more basic point; so I put *were* first and gave it an extra example, but left explicit mention of the issue for another day.  Like yesterday, for instance :-P

Comment: PLL, you are the best. Now I know how to use each correctly.

Answer (score 3):

If you weren't there, you should say

> I wish I could have been there the first time the baby kicked.

or

> I wish I had been there the first time the baby kicked.

You're asking about the tenses, but notice that I changed the latter half of the sentence as well. To say "for the baby kicking for the first time" sounds kind of awkward.

Comment: +1 — I think it’s the echoed *for* that makes the original version a bit clunky.  It’s not wrong, but as you say, it’s certainly awkward.

Comment: @PLL: Yes, and I just thought of something else about it that bothers me. When you say "for the baby kicking" sounds like the kind of kicking you hear in "ass-kicking" ... so a "baby-kicking" sounds like something I wouldn't want to attend.

Comment: Wow, it does sound ass-kicking! There are so many additional aspects that I could think of.