# Is it correct to say 'I wish some magic happens'?

Tags: grammaticality, subjunctive-mood, mood

Another read I come across in which a guy has written, "I wish you could see that young restless orphan who has no house to live in, none to get food from, whose pshychological centre has been damaged to the hilt. I wish you could see the pain of that abandoned girl on road who has set huge ambitions, but not priviliged enough to reach them, whose each tear drop brings earthquakes in the place on which it has fallen. **I wish some magic happens and brings** back all your lost senses and you start loving each and every human being going through hardships.

Is this at all correct to say **happens** after **wish** as the author has written above?

The writer is Indian. Not native.

Comment: How people write on Facebook, Twitter, and on the phone is one thing, how someone writes an article, a report, a study or a  a contemporary novel is another. You need to say 1. Where you found this sentence. 2. The context (although it's easy enough to guess) 3. Who said it? Was that person a native speaker or not. Was that person an American, British, Indian or non-native speaker? 4. Explain why you think it may be grammatically incorrect.

Comment: I will fix it, dear. Hold your horses.

Comment: 'I wish some magic happens', 'I want some magic happens', 'I desire some magic happens', 'I would like some magic happens',  'I need some magic happens' (and many other similar strings) are all ungrammatical.

Comment: So this is wrong?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - And yet "I hope some magic happens", "I suggest some magic happens", "I demand some magic happens" and others. Turned out interesting, this one. Any ideas for a pattern, principle or premise?

Comment: @ItWasLikeThatWhenIGotHere Then also, the [mandative]-subjunctive-or-is-it? is sometimes preferred by some: "I demand that some magic happen." // Verb affordances are very idiosyncratic.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Agreed, and I think Stuart is on to something below (I couldn't resist the present tense there, and I'm seasoned enough not to be affronted by "old-fashioned"). I'll leave the answer as is for the moment and see what lands on it overnight.

Comment: @FaizaaBashir What seems to be the issue with the clause?

Comment: @FaizaanBashir Please never call someone you don't know your “dear” like that in English. It will be perceived as condescending, patronizing, or a form of sexual harassment. It can only be used like that for true intimates, usually immediate family members such as one's spouse or from parent to child.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/62933 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/1066 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/5902 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/9158 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/37536 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/5056980 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/87354 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/218684 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/316034 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/390443 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/391503 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/76384 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/534917
and many more besides.

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot have a present-tense verb following *I wish that **X***.

That’s because you always have to ***backshift*** that next verb in **X** to make it unreal or hypothetical. After all, it’s a wish; it isn’t real. Therefore using the present tense  won’t work there. (By the way, *wish* is pretty much the last verb in English that still works this way. Even *hope* can take a non-backshifted present tense.)

Here though are valid and commonly used forms that are available to you for *wish*:

#### Present Tense: *I wish that...*

1. I **wish** she **called** first, but she **doesn’t**.
2. I **wish** she **would call** first, but she **doesn’t**.
3. I **wish** she **would call** first, but she **hasn’t**.
4. I **wish** she **had called** first, but she **didn’t**.
5. I **wish** she **would have called** first, but she **didn’t**.

#### Past Tense: *I wished that...*

6. I **wished** she **had called** first, but she **didn’t**.
7. I **had wished** she **would have called** first, but she **hadn’t**.

The most important thing is the last word in each version, the ones matching *X* in the parenthetical afterthought, *“but she **X**n’t”*. I don’t mean to say that we actually *say* that last part, but we always have its status in mind so that we know exactly what to choose for the two earlier clauses’ verb forms to convey the meaning given by the parenthetical.

Examples (1) and (2) with *doesn’t* are both talking about something habitual. It’s like she never does call first even though you wish she would do so. Maybe you’ve even asked her to do so, but it does no good to ask.

In example (3) with *hasn’t*, you’re still hoping she might call first. The event you’re wishing would happen still lies in the future, its outcome still unknown.

In examples (4) and (5) with *didn’t*, there is no chance of your wish coming true because it’s too late: the possibility lay in the past and she already did not call first. It can never come to pass.

In example (6) with *wished* and *didn’t*, the wishing itself is now in the past, but the outcome is the same: it did not happen. It’s too late for it to yet occur, just as in (4) and (5). Only when the wishing is taking place has moved into the past from the present.

The final example (7) with *had wished* and *hadn’t*, is far less common than the others because it’s using a more complex construction, the past perfect, which we often don’t bother with in English. Usually a simple past suffices. But the place you would be more apt to use this one is when you were narrating something in the past and needed to set up a condition that was even further back than the time you were narrating.

## But what about “the subjunctive”?

It was easier to explain how to use *wish* along with the simple verb *call*.
But with *be*
you **do** have another choice, and people who are fussy about using *were* for
hypotheticals instead of *was* when backshifting into the unreal will also elect to
use that special form here as well.

8. I always **wish** she **were** here now, but she never **is**.
9. I **wish** she **were** here now, but she **isn’t**.
10. I **wish** she **had been** here now, but she **isn’t**.
11. I **wish** she **had been** there then, but she **wasn’t**.
12. I **wished** she **had been** there then, but she **wasn’t**.
13. I **had wished** she **had been** there then, but she **wasn’t**.

Just as you cannot use present-tense *calls* after *I wish*, you also
cannot use the present-tense *can be* or *is able to be* following it,
either; You always have to backshift.

Here’s a backshifted *can be*, where present-tense *can* becomes past-tense *could*:

14. I always **wish** she **could be** here now, but she never **can (be)**.
15. I **wish** she **could be** here now, but she **can’t**.
16. I **wish** she **could have been** here now, but she **can’t**.
17. I **wish** she **could have been** there then, but she **couldn’t**.
18. I **wished** she **could have been** there then, but she **couldn’t**.
19. I **had wished** she **could have been** there then, but she **couldn’t**.

And here’s how you would do that same thing with the periphrastic version where we reword *can* + ɪɴꜰɪɴɪᴛɪᴠᴇ into an inflected form of *be able to* + ɪɴꜰɪɴɪᴛɪᴠᴇ, with allows the form of *be* chosen to now carry person, number, and inflectional tense or mood:

20. I always **wish** she **were** able to be here now, but she never **is**.
21. I **wish** she **were** able to be here now, but she **isn’t**.
22. I **wish** she **were** able to have been here now, but she **isn’t**.
23. I **wish** she **were** able to have been there then, but she **wasn’t**.
24. I **wished** she **were** able to have been there then, but she **wasn’t**.
25. I **had wished** she **had been** able to have been there then, but she **wasn’t**.

In some ways, it’s easier to use that last set than the set immediately previous to it.

Comment: This is all wishful thinking.

Comment: Don't most (younger?) people now say "I wish she was here now"?

Comment: @Mitch Only if they want [the Oscar-Meyer–wiener-jingle
cops](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/87356/2085) to come a-gunnin’ for ’em! I deliberately wrote ***“people who are fussy** about using* were *for hypotheticals instead of* was  *when backshifting into the unreal will also elect to use that special form here as well.”* Your English Comp grader ᴡɪʟʟ mark your paper down for this—and you for a bumpkin if you persist. It's always been considered a grammatical error by the educated here, which is why we had a wiener controversy in the first place. **Think of it as a *“class marker”.***

Answer (score -2):

It's correct, but it's a contraction. The writer appears to be saying "I wish that something magical happens...", which has "happens" after "wish". There's nothing wrong with that : "happens" is the verb in a subordinate / dependent clause.

Separating the main verb from the dependent clauses, we have "I wish / some magic happens / and brings back all your lost senses...".

Comment: No, this is a grammatical error. You can't have a regular present-tense verb after *I wish that*.

Comment: @tchrist - I agree that a conditional tense is better. (See what I did there? Almost said "would be" from force of habit...)

Comment: The OED suggests this sense is old-fashioned but either present subjunctive or indicative can be used ("(b) with object clause with may or (formerly) present subjunctive, occasionally indicative: expressing a desire that the event may happen or that the fact may prove to be so"). It has examples of both, although in many cases it's impossible to differentiate subjunctive and indicative.

Comment: Wish can easily be used with the present tense. This happens all the time when people blow out candles on a birthday cake or break a wishbone: I wish that your coming year is a good one. I wish that one of us wins the lottery.

Comment: @GlobalCharm Nope, those are ungrammatical in my language. That sounds like some sort of blunder that little kids might say before they’ve been through grammar school to learn them how not to have missaid things.

Comment: @ItWasLikeThatWhenIGotHere English does not have a “conditional tense”.